# Disable/Enable slider functionality on window resize

Tags: javascript, slider, swiper.js

I am using Swiper slider and I would like to disable it for desktop so the interface looks a little different.

The way I achieved this was to create a onload event listener and and check the screen size to create a new Swiper element.

```
window.addEventListener("load", toggleSlider);
function toggleSlider() {
  var w = window.innerWidth;
  var container = document.getElementsByClassName("swiper-container");
  if ( w < 768 ) {
    var mySwiper = new Swiper(container, {
      // Optional parameters
```

What I would like to accomplish is to be able to toggle this functionality on windows resize without having to reload the page.
Something like:

```
 if ( w < 768 ) {
    var mySwiper = new Swiper(...
 }else{
  delete Swiper
 }
```

I tried deleting the Object `Swiper`, since the code create a `new Swiper()`, but it didn't work.

Any Ideas on how it can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Select the DOM element and then destroy it.

```
e.g const mySwiepr = document...select it as you wish.

mySwiper.destroy(deleteInstance, cleanStyles);
```

Destroy slider instance and detach all events listeners, where:

deleteInstance - boolean - Set it to false (by default it is true) to not to delete Swiper instance

cleanStyles - boolean - Set it to true (by default it is true) and all custom styles will be removed from slides, wrapper and container.
Useful if you need to destroy Swiper and to init again with new options or in different direction

You need a .('resize') handler as well which to checks

```
if (condition) {select carousel then mySwiper.destroy()}
```

[doc reference](https://idangero.us/swiper/api/)

Comment: I get an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: deleteInstance is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:18

Comment: deleteInstance and cleanStyles are Boolean parameters ilke  mySwiper.destroy(true, true) and they are optional (true by default), check the documentation.

Simply remove both to test. e.g call only mySwiper.destroy()

Comment: I get an error: TypeError: swiper.destroy is not a function. I looked into the reference, unfortunately could not solve it